# Nested SQL to find the values when one field is true

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, the first one of them is `orderbook` has a field namely 
`easy_order` with datatype of `tinyint(1)` and the primary key is `id`.

The second table name is `execution` including the fields of `buy_order_id` and `sell_order_id`. These 2 fields are ref. from the `id` key from the `orderbook` table.

I would like to write a SQL to find all the rows from the `execution` table whose  `buy_order_id` OR `sell_order_id` row from the `orderbook` table has the `easy_order` column value of 1.

I use MySQL database.

Comment: Did you try anything? This should be easy. What problem did you have?

Comment: What have you tried so far???  Also before asking a question, learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: add  a proper data sample .  . the expected  result and  your code

Comment: It felt quite intimidating initially, but, I make it work and write an asnwer.

Comment: @Eric  would you please remove the downvote?

Comment: Please, do not accuse users about votes. Firstly, you don't know who downvoted it. Secondly, you already commented after them, so in case it was them, they should get a notification, and they can then decide whether to change their vote based on the update. If they don't decide to, it seems better just to move on, rather than to continue litigating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it this way, avoiding repetition and dual nested `select`s:

```
select execution.*
from execution
inner join orderbook on
    orderbook.id in (execution.buy_order_id, execution.sell_order_id) and
    orderbook.easy_order = 1;
```

(You may prefer conceptually to put `orderbook.easy_order = 1` in a `where` clause. It will produce the same results, so it's a matter of preference.)

Comment: It's great and I think your way is better. Would you please remove the downvote?

Comment: I'm glad it helps. However, I didn't even downvote, and either way, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945077/nested-sql-to-find-the-values-when-one-field-is-true/49945235#comment86906786_49945077).

Comment: Ok no problem. Thaks

Answer (score 1):

I make it work The SQL is,

```
SELECT * FROM  execution WHERE buy_order_id IN (SELECT id FROM orderbook WHERE easy_order=1) 
OR 
sell_order_id IN (SELECT id FROM orderbook WHERE easy_order=1);
```